# I can't Update bluetooth device on using Android 9 or + and using Plugin.BLE Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, bluetooth

I can get info and update device bluetooth on iPhone and old versions Android.
But i can't use await characteristic.StartUpdateAsync() on Android 9 and 10.

In iOS or other versions android on try await characterist.StartUpdateAsync() dont stop the app and get more info from device.

My Code:

public async void GetDevice(IAdapter adapter)
{

```
        try
        {

            if (bluetoothLE.State == BluetoothState.Off)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Atenção", "É necessário estar com o Bluetooh ativado.", "ok");
                return;
            }


            var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
            if (location == null)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Atenção", "É necessário estar com a localização ativada.", "ok");
                return;
            }

            adapter.ScanTimeout = 20000;
            adapter.ScanMode = ScanMode.Balanced;


            adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (objeto, a) =>
            {
                if (a.Device.Name != null  && a.Device.Name.ToLower().Contains("luckie"))
                {
                    device = a.Device;
                }
            };


            await adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();

            if (device != null)
            {
                await adapter.StopScanningForDevicesAsync();
                await adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(device);

                var services = await device.GetServicesAsync();

                foreach (var service in services)
                {
                    var caracteristicas = await service.GetCharacteristicsAsync();


                    foreach (var carac in caracteristicas)
                    {
                        //Bug android 9 ou > -- Problemas ao notificar o device
                        //Checa se é Bateria ou Temperatura
                        if (carac.Uuid == "2a19" || carac.Uuid == "2a1c"
                            || carac.Name.ToLower().Equals("temperature measurement")
                            || carac.Name.ToLower().Equals("battery level"))
                        {
                            
                            carac.ValueUpdated += (o, args) =>
                            {
                                var bytes = args.Characteristic.Value;
                            };

                            await carac.StartUpdatesAsync();

                            //Temperatura
                            if (carac.Uuid == "2a1c" || carac.Name.ToLower().Equals("temperature measurement"))
                            {
                                byte[] byteValues = carac.Value;
                                string hexadecimal = BitConverter.ToString(byteValues);
                                string[] hexSplit = hexadecimal.Split('-');

                                //Temperatura
                                string medicaoHex = "0x" + hexSplit[2] + hexSplit[1];
                                string result = Convert.ToInt32(medicaoHex, 16).ToString();
                                string temperatura = result.Substring(0, 2) + "," + result.Substring(2, 2);

                                //Horário
                                string horaHex = "0x" + hexSplit[9];
                                string minutoHex = "0x" + hexSplit[10];
                                string segundoHex = "0x" + hexSplit[11];

                                int hora = Convert.ToInt32(horaHex, 16);
                                int minuto = Convert.ToInt32(minutoHex, 16);
                                int segundo = Convert.ToInt32(segundoHex, 16);
                                TimeSpan horario = new TimeSpan(hora, minuto, segundo);

                                temperature.Text = temperatura + "º";

                                titleTemperature.Text = "Ultima medição em " + minuto + " minutos";

                                activeLoad.IsRunning = false;
                                activeLoad.IsVisible = false;

                                frameTemperature.IsVisible = true;
                            }

                            if (carac.CanRead)
                            {
                                if (carac.Uuid == "2a19" || carac.Name.ToLower().Equals("battery level"))
                                {
                                    byte[] byteValues = carac.Value;
                                    string hexadecimal = BitConverter.ToString(byteValues);
                                    int batteryLevel = 0;
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hexadecimal))
                                    {
                                        string[] hexSplit = hexadecimal.Split('-');

                                        //Bateria
                                        string batteryHex = "0x" + hexadecimal;
                                        batteryLevel = Convert.ToInt32(batteryHex, 16);
                                    }

                                }


                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            } else
            {
                activeLoad.IsVisible = false;
                titleTemperature.Text = "Nenhum dispositivo foi encontrado. " +
                    "Verifique se você está próximo a algum dispositivo.";

            }


        } catch(DeviceConnectionException ex)
        {
         await DisplayAlert("Atenção", "Não foi possível conectar " + ex.DeviceName, "ok");
        }
        
    }
```

thanks for help me.

Comment: Hi, do you mean `StartUpdateAsync` only works in old android devices, and new devices work?

Comment: Hi, yes. Old versions android works normality. But on android 9 or higher on call startUpdatesAsync() skip code.

Comment: Okey, it‘s strange. Maybe you could submit an issue [here](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le/issues) in Github. Then later can follow it up.

Comment: Thank's for help me. I added issue on page project. 
https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le/issues/459

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT 
I believe the problem is on Samsung not in Android.
I test on other devices within adroid 10 and Sansung is unique android skip code.

Comment: Oh, Samsung device again. It always gives me special surprises. :-(